# Proper return type for dictionary function

Tags: typescript

I have this simple function:

```
export function toDictionary<T>(items: T[], getKey: (item: T) => string) {
    const result = [...items];

    for (const item of items) {
        const key = getKey(item);
        if(result[key]) {
            throw new Error(`Key value ${key} is not unique.`);
        }
        result[key] = item;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I would like to specify the return type of this function in a way that intellisense will show me the properties.

Example:

```
const dictionary = toDictionary([{
    type: 'list',
    url: 'http://example/list'
}, {
    type: 'details',
    url: 'http://example/{0}/details'
}], x => x.type);
```

Typescript should know that `dictionary.list` and `dictionary.details` exist.

Is this possible somehow? I am open to changing anything in this implementation code. All of the data is available at build time, i.e. it is static, hardcoded data.

Comment: Any property can be the key ?

Comment: It's always a property whose value is unique in the items in the array, so there will be no collision (updated implementation, to ensure this). Also, it's always a string, so no collision with the array indexes either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is to get the compiler to infer literal types for properties where these could end up being used as the keys of the dictionary. The compiler will infer a literal type if the literal is assigned to a location that extends a generic type parameter of a type that can be narrowed to a literal.

So in our case if we use this constraint we will get literal types for `type`: `T extends Record<string, P | object>, P extends PropertyKey`.

If we also add a type parameter for the return type of the `getKey` function (let's say `K`) we can type the result as `T[] & Record<K, T>`.

Putting it together we get:

```
export function toDictionary<T extends Record<string, P | object>, P extends PropertyKey, K extends Extract<T[keyof T], PropertyKey>>(items: T[], getKey: (item: T) => K): T[] & Record<K, T> {
    const result = [...items];

    for (const item of items) {
        result[getKey(item) as number] = item;
    }

    return result as T[] & Record<K, T>;
}

const dictionary = toDictionary([{
    type: 'list',
    o: { data: "" },
    url: 'http://example/list'
}, {
    type: 'details',
    o: { data: "" }, // just to show we can nest objects 
    url: 'http://example/{0}/details'
}], x => x.type);

dictionary.details.url // ok
```

Now the disadvantage of this is that literal types will be inferred for ALL properties, including `url` for example (as well as any other `string` or `number` properties). This might be a bit distracting.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It looks like the disadvantage doesn't actually exist - at least not in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). Can you confirm and explain this? I mean, `K` will contain all string and number properties, but on `dictionary` only the correct ones seem to appear.

Comment: Can you also please explain the function of `PropertyKey`? Why can't we simply use `string`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `PropertyKey` is `string | number | symbol` you can also use `string`, `PropertyKey` allows for all possible key types. If I hover over `url` I see ` "http://example/list" | "http://example/{0}/details"`

Comment: But with `string` instead of `PropertyKey` it actually stops working. Hover: ah, I see, that's what you meant. But you can confirm that - if we change the `url` values from URLs to valid identifier names like `'listUrl'` and `'detailsUrl'` - that `dictionary.detailsUrl` will be marked as invalid by typescript?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it works for me with string too.. Not sure what you mean by the last part. You can use `url ` as a key too.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript (clue in the name) is typed. If you are looking for return type which will handle this, maybe you should create own `Dictionary<T>` type and then return it in `toDictionary` function. I think that's the only way to make intellisense work the way you like.

Comment: I am looking for an advanced type definition here, that uses the power of typescript to derive the type. It's obvious that I could just create a definition manually, but I want to avoid this.